# WPF - The name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I know there are a lot of questions on this subject and I have read most of them and tried out most of the suggestions without any success.

I have deleted the bin, obj and .vs folders, closed visual studio, rebooted my laptop amongst other things.

I am new to WPF and xaml so any help would be much appreciated. I am using Visual Studio 2022

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Datagrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Datagrid;assembly=WPF_Datagrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Songs/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DG" ></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

**CS Code**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace WPF_Datagrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //DG.ItemsSource = Songs.GetSongs();
        }

        public class Songs
        {
            public List<Song> SongList { get; set; } = GetSongs();
            public static List<Song> GetSongs()
            {
                var file = @"C:\Users\*********\Documents\Songs.csv";
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                var list = new List<Song>();    
                for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    var line = lines[i].Split(',');
                    var song = new Song() 
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(line[0]),
                        Artist = line[1], 
                        Title = line[3] 
                    };
                    list.Add(song);
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
        public class Song
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Artist { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `<local:Songs/>` expects class Songs in the namespace WPF_Datagrid. That is not the case, because you have declared it as inner class in MainWindow.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to put every class into its own file, so extracting the classes `Song` and `Songs` to their separate files helps you to have more clean project structure. They can further be placed into `Model` and `DataAccess` folders if you want to have more hierarchy.